# Pause method whild asynctask runs HTTPGET

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a `run()` method and in it i'm executing an Asynctask which is doing HTTPGET. How can I make `run()` wait for the Asynctask to get results and then continue?

Comment: You need to provide more information in your question. Does `run()` method executes in a separate thread ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//like this
    asyncRequest(URL, parameters, "POST",new RequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(String response) { 
                    /*@todo get results and then continue */
                }

                @Override
                public void onIOException(IOException ex) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException ex) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException ex) {
                }
            }); 

public static void asyncRequest(final String requestUrl,final Bundle parameters,final String httpMethod,final RequestListener requestListener) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String resp = MyUtil.openUrl(requestUrl, httpMethod, parameters);
                    requestListener.onComplete(resp);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    requestListener.onFileNotFoundException(ex);
                            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                                requestListener.onMalformedURLException(ex);
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                requestListener.onIOException(ex);
                            }
            }
        }.start();
}

public static interface RequestListener {
    public void onComplete(String response);

    public void onIOException(IOException ex);

    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException ex);

    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException ex);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Execute the run function in the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask

```
    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //do long asynctask activity here
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           run(); //executes the run method you want here after asysnctask is completed
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
      }

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
      }
}
```

Comment: that's what I thought but the run method is being run from a broadcastReceiver which is passing Context, and Strings